# Why are there 2 connectors on li-ion batteries

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, terminal

I'm looking at just about any assembled li-ion battery pack for sale and they all have 2 connectors coming out (4 wires total) and I'm wondering why is that?

Comment: Extra two wires for a temperature sensor.

Comment: @Andyaka so you mean to tell me that every single one (that I found, even chinese ones) battery seller adds a thermocouple to their packs, without a miss? This doesn't seem very realistic :?

Comment: I'm saying nothing of the sort and YOU are not supplying details of the specific pack you are investigating.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Whether there is *actually* a temperature sensor in the pack may or may not be so; the 4 wires are standard and so are provided (and also make it seem as if the battery meets regulations).

Comment: Yeah, you should really ask the seller. If they can't answer an important question like that, then simply don't buy from them.

Comment: @Andyaka well I literally mean just about any one you find, but [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/ELECTRIC-BIKE-36V-volt-14ah-18650-lithium-E-Bike-Battery-pack-Charger/392402936738?_trkparms=aid%3D555018%26algo%3DPL.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131003132420%26meid%3D0f69146f403846caaffaf77fc0753aa9%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D12%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D282763823611%26itm%3D392402936738%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2047675&_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851) is one for example. You can clearly see 2 connectors on the image and it does not look like a thermo sensor connector to me.

Comment: Don't buy important stuff from ebay is my policy. Don't buy components that don't have a data sheet is my other policy.

Comment: @Andyaka your policies are reasonable but my wallet has the final call, sadly. I'm just curious why they put 2 connectors on batteries, and it's just about any battery I literally could not find one with just 2 terminals sticking out.

Comment: Looking at that eBay unit, it appears to me that the connector with the red/black wires is to be permanently attached to the ebike circuitry while the black cable with the barrel connector is for connecting the external charger. Presumably they are simply in parallel. Assuming you are looking exclusively at ebike packs, that may be a de-facto standard.

Comment: @DoxyLover that's what I assumed too but I just got an answer from what looks like a reputable [german battery pack provider](https://www.akkushop.de/) and they told me that the battery should only be charged through the "charge port" without specifying any particular reason, which doesn't really make much sense to me.

Comment: Among the various options it could be: a) balance lines for intermediate cells, b) an I2C or SMBus line to a management controller, c) a thermistor, d) some pull-up/down for presence detection ... Impossible to say without the spec.

Comment: Your experience of battery packs is much more limited than what some of us have been exposed to. I think DoxyLover is correct for the pack you are looking at, but without having the picture in the question, the other answers were totally reasonable. There are many, many different types and sizes of battery packs and not all of them have two connectors, and for those that do, there are multiple reasons why. Some may have data + power, some may have thermistors etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Li-ion Ebike batteries often have a built-in BMS (Battery Management System) or PCM (Protection Circuit Module) that prevents over-charge, over-discharge, high temperature or excessive current draw, and may also have a balancer to keep all the cell voltages equal. As the normal discharge current may be 40A or more, Some have a separate connection that provides extra protection for low current charging.

Here is an example:-

[28S LiFePO4 Li-ion smart bms pcm for 28s battery pack](http://www.rjxzstech.com/product/28S-BMS.html)

[image]

Cheaper batteries sold on eBay etc. might have direct connections to the battery for discharge and a low current BMS for charging, or the charge port might be connected directly to the battery and is for convenience only. Without seeing inside the pack it's impossible to say what a particular battery has if the supplier can't tell you. Buyer beware!

Comment: So basically I'm going to have a hard time using the load path for charging in regenerative braking, I will have to design it in a way that it feeds into the charger circuit, given the image in the answer. I'll probably get a cheaper-ish one from ebay for the sake of it and see what's going on inside anyway.

Comment: The discharge connector can also be used for fast _charging_, as it won't have the lower over-current protection of the charge port.  Essentially it can be considered a direct connection to the battery under normal circumstances. You probably should monitor regen voltage and current separately, particularly when the battery is close to fully charged (since it cannot take any more charge without going over-voltage). This could occur if eg. the bike was run down-hill with a full charge.

Answer (score 0):

2 wires connect to the battery, and in general the extra 2 wires connect to a thermistor to allow temperature sensing of the battery. Although for more efficient wiring this could be done with a common ground giving a total of 3 wires, which is rarely seen.

Comment: It might seem efficient but it would make the thermistor signal bounce around with the voltage fluctuations at the battery end of the ground wire caused by changes in load/charge current.

Comment: Common connection is often used in Nicad/NiMH packs where the temperature sensor is monitored during charging only, and the charger can stop charging for a short time while measuring temperature (or doesn't care if the temperature reading isn't exact).